# In MySQL, is there any performance difference between executing insert with 5 fields and executing insert with 30 fields?

Tags: mysql, json, performance, insert, field

Let's suppose I have a table in MySQL with 50 columns, and I'm continuously inserting registers and updating them.

Usually I insert registers in this table with about 30 or 40 fields, but this table began to have too much information and when there are many people working on it my system becomes a little slower.

So, I've got the idea of putting everything in one field in a json, and later, when activity is down, make a robot read every json data in every register and update all the fields so performance never gets compromised at high activity hours.

Could this work? Or an insert with 5 fields is the same with 30 fields? Thank you!

Comment: You could test this in a fraction of the time it took to ask this question

Comment: You could have answered this question even in less time. I think you didn't even understand the question, this is something i can not test in production.

Comment: Me? I couldn't, but maybe others could

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a few of of the `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs`.  We need to see the datatypes, indexes, and unique keys.  (and possibly other things.)  Slowdowns could be caused by too many _or_ too few indexes; I need details.

Comment: My point is, the 5 vs 30 is _probably not_ the issue.  With more details, we can help you find the _real_ issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do any benchmarking?  If there are indexes using any of the fields you want to defer setting, that would make a difference, but possibly making all the new rows have null or the default value for those columns might make it worse, not better.  If no indexes are involved, I don't know if you would see any significant difference, maybe if there were blob or text fields involved it would.

It sounds like you do have a need to do the inserts right away, but only some of the data is critical to have up to date.  If that's the case, you might do better do have a table just for that critical data, and the rest of the data for each row in a detail table.